# Compensation for an EU flight

Tags: air-travel, compensation

Few months ago I flew with IranAir from Rome to Tehran. Our flight was delayed by 7 hours! I claimed compensation and they offered me 25% off on my next flight which sounds funny, cause according to law I'm entitled to get up to 600€. I placed the issue on Resolver.com, after 3 months they replied saying call this number to follow your compensation. It's been a month since I first called them and sent them my bank information. Called another 3 times and the only thing they keep saying is that it's in process, and they don't give me a date or anything! What should I do now?!

Answer (score 5):

You should contact Iran Air and remind them of your rights and their obligations under the EU Air Passenger Rights Directive:

> in the event of a delay longer than three hours, ***passengers should be offered reimbursement within seven days*** (and, if necessary, a free flight to the initial point of departure) ***and compensation as in the event of cancellation***

http://www.europarl.europa.eu/atyourservice/en/displayFtu.html?ftuId=FTU_5.6.2.html

Should Iran Air continue to avoid compensating you, you should lodge an official complaint with them, using the [EU Complaint Form](https://ec.europa.eu/transport/sites/transport/files/themes/passengers/air/doc/complain_form/eu_complaint_form_en.pdf).

Should Iran Air still avoid the issue, you then send a copy of that complaint to the [relevant national enforcement body](https://ec.europa.eu/transport/sites/transport/files/themes/passengers/air/doc/2004_261_national_enforcement_bodies.pdf) of the EU Member that you flew out of (Italy).

Using a third party claims company is pointless because they literally do not do anything more than you would do - they submit the paperwork required.  They won't chase, they won't follow the case up, because all of that cuts into their pay - you have literally signed away a portion of any compensation for no benefit at all.

You should check your agreement with Resolver.com, because its highly likely that you have to pay them a portion of your compensation regardless of whether you receive it because of their actions or not once you have engaged them as your agent in this matter.

Comment: I think the OP means https://www.resolver.co.uk/, which is a completely free service. I don't believe the OP has signed away any compensation at all. I don't believe they are an "agent", I believe they just provide a standardised way to complain, which makes it easier for both the consumer and the company. I agree that they don't do any chasing for you.